# Use O(n^2) time to fix a mistake in bipartite matching

Tags: algorithm, graph, linear-programming, bipartite

This is a problem from Algorithm Design book.

Given a bipartite graph with vertices G=(V,E) where V=(A,B) such that |A|=|B|=n.

We manage to perfectly match n-2 nodes in A to n-2 nodes in B. However, for the remaining two nodes in A we map them both to a certain node in B (not one of the n-2 nodes in B that are already matched to.)

Given the information from the "matching" above, how to use O(n^2) time to decide whether a perfect matching between A and B actually exists? A hint is fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have u and v be the two nodes in A that match to the same node x in B. Pick one of those two nodes - call it u - and remove the edge to x from the matching. You are now left with a graph where you have a matching between n - 1 of the nodes from A and n - 1 of the nodes from B. The question now is whether you can extend this matching to make it even bigger.

There's a really nice way to do this using Berge's theorem, which says that a matching in a graph is maximum if and only if there is no alternating path between two unmatched nodes. (An alternating path is one that alternates between using edges not included in the matching and edges included in the matching). You can find a path like this by starting from  the node u and trying to find a path to x by doing a modified binary search, where when you go from A to B you only follow unmatched edges and when you go from B back to A you only follow matched edges. If an alternating path exists from u to x, then you'll be sure to find it this way, and if no such path exists, then you can be certain of that as well.

If you do find an alternating path from u to x, you can "flip" it to increase the size of the matching by one. Specifically, take all the edges in the path that aren't in the matching and add them in, and take all the edges that were in the matching and delete them. The resulting is still a valid matching that has one more edge in it than what you started with (if you don't see why this is, play around with some examples and see what you find, or look at the proof of Berge's theorem).

Overall, this approach will require time O(m + n), where m is the number of edges in the graph and n is the number of nodes. The number of edges m is at most O(n<sup>2</sup>) in a bipartite graph, so this matches your time bound (and, in fact, is actually a bit tighter!)

Comment: Thank you very much! I just turned this into a network flow problem in my answer (this problem is taken from the network flow section of the book.)

Answer (score 0):

Transform this problem to the max flow min cut problem by adding a source s which is connected to A by unit capacity edges and a sink t to which B is connected by unit capacity edges.

As templatetypedef said in their answer, we already have a flow of size n-1 on this network.

The problem is now to determine whether the size of the flow can be increased to n. This can be achieved by running one round of Edmonds-Karp heuristic which takes O(E)=O(n^2) time (i.e find the shortest path in the residual graph of the flow of size n-1 above and look for the bottleneck edge.)